# How to resolve parameterized class at runtime?

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, aspnetboilerplate

I have a view model like this:

```cs
public ViewModelSample(MyClass a)
{
}
```

I tried to resolve this by:

```cs
var myClassObj = new MyClass();
var vm = IocManager.Resolve<T>(myClassObj); // where args = object of MyClass
```

Signature `IIocResolver . T Resolve<T> (object argumentsAsAnonymousType);`

If I were to do this from `System.Activator`, then I would call `return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), myClassObj);` and it works fine.

Also, if `ViewModelSample` is only having parameterless constructor, then it does resolve it fine.

I am getting the exception:

> Missing dependency. Component
>   ViewModels.ViewModelSample has a
>   dependency on
>   Dto.MyClass, which could
>   not be resolved. Make sure the dependency is correctly registered in
>   the container as a service, or provided as inline argument.

`MyClass` is a simple DTO, so it's not inheriting `ITransientDependency`. Moreover, I want to assign this value at runtime.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Supplying runtime data during construction into [injectables](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/) (assuming your `ViewModelSample` *is* an injectable) might not be the best approach, as described [here](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data/).

Comment: Besides that, in MVC-styled web applications, View Models are typically simple data holders that don't contain any dependencies or application logic. In that sense it is not usual to resolve View Models through the container. Likewise, in your example, `ViewModelSample` has no dependencies that come from the Windsor. Instead, consider creating `ViewModelSample` using the C# `new` keyword: `new ViewModelSample(new MyClass())`.

Comment: Thanks for reference, its enlightening . ViewModel in my application is inheriting some services which have depenedencies. I had `new` approach  but thought it would be useful with DI , may be for testing in future. The AspNetzero samples are instantiating through DI or `System.Activator`, so I am cleaning code up. Parameterless Viewmodel was getting created fine.  Thanks to @aaron parameterized is working fine with IoCManager now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Signature `IIocResolver . T Resolve<T> (object argumentsAsAnonymousType);`

In this case, `new { a = myClassObj }` since `a` is the name of your parameter.

```cs
var vm = IocManager.Resolve<ViewModelSample>(new { a = myClassObj });
```

## Reference

Anonymous Types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types